# pass DEVNAME as argument to a script in udevrules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, libudev

I am trying to catch devtype=usb_interface and pass devname of the usb_device it came from, kinda like this:
`ACTION=="add" ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_interface"   RUN+="/path/to/exec/exec_41_udevrules.py '%E{ACTION}' '%E{DEVNAME}'"`
problem is passing DEVNAME like this doesn't work, it passes as empty variable.

Here is the output of `sudo udevadm monitor --udev --subsystem-match=usb --property` when I plug an usb modem:
https://termbin.com/m458

So in this example, I'd like to pass /dev/bus/usb/002/111 (devname) at every devtype usb_interface add event

Comment: Perhaps it is `%N`?

Comment: @lan Abbott I'll give it a try a bit later and post an update